# Chrome拡張を公開する際、開発者用アカウントの作成が推奨されるのは、なぜですか？

Tags: chrome-web-store

#### やりたいこと

Chrome拡張をChromeウェブストアに公開したいです。

#### 質問

「Publish in the Chrome Web Store」ページには、以下のように記載されています。

> We suggest using a new account just for your app instead of your personal account.

https://developers.chrome.com/webstore/publish#create-a-developer-account

なぜ、開発者用アカウントの作成が推奨されているのでしょうか？
私は、普段使っているGoogleアカウントで、Chrome拡張を公開しようと考えていました。